# EF6 Winforms BindingSource Refresh

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview, bindingsource

I must be doing something wrong or this wouldn't be so confusing.  I'm making a Winforms app and child records are opening up in a new form on a grid.  When I save my changes and go back to the parent form I'd like to see the changes in the totals.  These are POCO objects.  What is the proper way to do that?  I need something like a refresh so I can see the changes in the other context.

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        loadData();
    }

    private void loadData()
    {
        if (_context != null)
            _context.Dispose();

        _context = new ModelContainer();

        _context.Customers.Where(c => c.BranchId == this.branchId || this.branchId == 0).Load();

        this.customerBindingSource.DataSource = _context.Customers.Local.ToBindingList();

        _context.Branches.Where(b => b.BranchId == this.branchId || this.branchId == 0).Load();

        this.branchBindingSource.DataSource = _context.Branches.Local.ToBindingList();

        customerBindingSource.ResetBindings(true);

        customerBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void customerDataGridView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int customerId = 0;

        ...

        Locations locations = new Locations(customerId);
        locations.ShowDialog();

        ...

        loadData();
    }
```

That all works fine.  After I show my child form I have to call loadData() again.  Isn't there a right/better way?

Comment: It would be nice to see how you are passing records between forms and how you are doing changes to them

Comment: I agree Sergey, DarrenD: it really depends on when you are calculating your totals.

Comment: I'm using form inheritance.  Should my forms only have one datacontext in the base?  I would see all the changes across all forms since I'm using an ObservableCollection?